# Matplotlib boxplot without outliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, outliers

Is there any way of hiding the outliers when plotting a boxplot in matplotlib (python)?

I'm using the simplest way of plotting it:

```
  from pylab import *
  boxplot([1,2,3,4,5,10])
  show()
```

This gives me the following plot:

(I cannot post the image because I have not enough reputation, but basically it is a boxplot with Q1 at y=1, Q3 at y=5, and the outlier at y=10)

I would like to remove the outlier at y=10, so that the plot only shows from Q1 to Q3 (in this case from 1 to 5).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In current versions of matplotlib you can do:

```
boxplot([1,2,3,4,5,10], showfliers=False)
```

or

```
boxplot([1,2,3,4,5,10], sym='')
```

In older versions, only the second approach will work.

The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) for `boxplot` do mention this, btw as, "Enter an empty string (‘’) if you don’t want to show fliers.", though, at least for myself, "outliers" is the more familiar word.

Comment: That definitely does it. My fault... didn't read the doc carefully (just looked for outlier, not for flier!).

Comment: No problem, and it would be hard to find in the docs if you didn't know it already -- I had the advantage of going to other way.  (I'll edit my answer to sound like was less obvious, since it wasn't particularly clear.)

Comment: @DidacBusquets Just want to chime in here and say that in v1.4, you'll be able to pass a `showfliers=False` option when you call boxplot.

Comment: @Paul H: please feel free to edit my answer when this becomes readily available.

Comment: In matplotlib 1.2 outliers are hidden with `boxplot(data,0,'')`. See (http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/pyplot_api.html)